# Is there a way to remove overlaying events in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Is it possible to change behavior of these events to stack next too each other instead of overlaying?

[image]

Comment: I've added a related question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202000/calculate-left-positioning-in-div-jquery

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Google Calendar doesn't provide any option to not overlay events. A browser extension could technically take care of that, but I am not aware of any offering such option (e.g. see the list of extensions for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=google%20calendar%20&appver=&platform=) and [Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/google%20calendar) pertaining to Google Calendar).